# What should i do when an amqp channel is closed on error?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

As I understand there are some errors in AMQP which cause the channel to force-close. ([Such as sending to a non-existent exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8839398/961581))

Why is this? And what should an application do?

The close could cause consumers, bindings, queues and exchanges to be deleted. The java client supports recovering these things on network failure through AutorecoveringConnection, but the same doesn't happen for this case.

Comment: Have a look at the [AMQP specification §2.3.6 Error Handling](https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf) `[...] An exception closes the channel or connection, and
returns a reply code and reply text to the client application...[...]`. Closing channel/connection may be the best solution to exclude unhealthy clients. Have a look too at [Automatically reconnect RabbitMQ channels](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19575837/564005)

Comment: Thanks - Lyra does seem to fill gaps left in recovery strategies in the java client - I'll looks into it more. 
I'm considering whether to go with this or to explicitly do all the state-changing operations in a channel initialisation method which could be re-called for a reconnection strategy.

Comment: One idea could be to create a new `Channel` to publish your message and closing it afterwards. Your receiving channels with consumers will not be effected by the error that occurred when sending the message.