# RabbitMQ com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already closed due to connection error

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq as a broker, to dispatch the request and response between my different applications. While i am facing a weird behavior from the rabbitmq. It gives me this exception after processing 2500 to 3000 records.

> com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already
>   closed due to connection error; cause: java.net.SocketException:
>   Connection reset  at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:195)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.5.6.jar:na]   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:309)
>   ~[amqp-client-3.5.6.jar:na]

One more thing when i tried to run it my client with **2 second delay** between the messages, this issue did occur. This is the code i am trying to publish the message.

```
     try {
          byte[] e = jsonMessage.getBytes(RabbitConf.COMMUNICATION_ENCODING);
          this.channel.basicPublish(exchangeType.name(), rountingKey.name(), (BasicProperties)null, e);
      } catch (IOException var6) {
          this.LOG.error("IOException when sending data to rabbit:", var6);
       }
```

I am using amqp-client 3.6.0 for my client. 
Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839094/why-do-my-rabbitmq-channels-keep-closing

Comment: thanks @Rupesh, but this i tried this solution and it is also not working.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this problem? I am facing the same problem with RabbitMQ 3.6.6

Comment: I am facing the same, Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try playing with the `qos` value (although it is unclear from the docs if this has an effect on the *publish* side):

```
this.channel.basicQos(1);
```

See: http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#basicQos-int-.