# RabbitMQ channel getting closed

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am working on a project using spring-boot and RabbitMQ. I have two queues on RabbitMQ to which events are listened.

If I start the process, it runs fine for a few hours but after that the below exceptions are logged and all the message are in the RabbitMQ queue and are not being processed.

```
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to clean channel shutdown; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=OK, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:198)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:312)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:306)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicAck(ChannelN.java:1165)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:955)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.basicAck(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 2930, class-id=60, method-id=80)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:198)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:312)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:306)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicAck(ChannelN.java:1165)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:955)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.basicAck(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

These errors some time occur in one of the listeners and sometimes both. Once these start coming, the queue processing completely stops. They start working after multiple restarts of the server (Java)

This is my Config:

```
  @Bean
  public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
        new CachingConnectionFactory(rabbitmqUrl);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitmqUser);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitmqPassword);
    return connectionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  SimpleMessageListenerContainer containerQ1(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                           @Qualifier("RabbitMQQ1IndexUpdateListenerAdapter") MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queue1);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(2);
    container.setMessageConverter(jackson2Converter());
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    container.setPrefetchCount(30000);
    return container;
  }

  @Bean
  SimpleMessageListenerContainer containerQ2(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                           @Qualifier("RabbitMQQ2IndexUpdateListenerAdapter") MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queue2);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(2);
    container.setMessageConverter(jackson2Converter());
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    container.setPrefetchCount(30000);
    return container;
  }

  @Bean(name = "RabbitMQQ1IndexUpdateListenerAdapter")
  @Primary
  MessageListenerAdapter Q1listenerAdapter(RabbitMQESIndexUpdateListener receiver) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver);
  }

  @Bean(name = "RabbitMQQ2IndexUpdateListenerAdapter")
  MessageListenerAdapter Q2listenerAdapter(RabbitMQQ2IndexUpdateListener receiver) {
     return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver);
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageConverter jackson2Converter() {
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    converter.setJsonObjectMapper(mapper);
    return converter;
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: Possibly a double-acknowledgement? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817435/314291

Comment: How can I verify that? I went through the code and logic seems fine. Any other way to confirm that?

Comment: try setting automatic recovery `connectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);`

Comment: there is no such method present in the container.