# rabbitmq: channel level exception recovery

Tags: rabbitmq

I am working on a worker service that consume from rabbitmq queue and I am trying to figure out how to handle channel shut down event, for example: lets say my consumer didn't ack the broker for 30 minutes and the broker shut down the channel for that.

I know the rabbitmq clinet library (I am using the C# library) will automatically try to re-connect on connection shut down, but what is the best practice for when the connection is alive but the channel was closed? I can register handler for the 'Channel Shut Down' event but what should I do inside this handler except for logging it? I want to keep consuming from the the relevant queue after all.

here is my code, i tried to create the channel again but i get timeout exception for that:

```
    var consumer = ...
        
    channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
        
    channel.BasicQos(0, 100, false);
        
    channel.ModelShutdown += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Log.Error($"channel was shut down");
                            channel = _connection.CreateModel();
                            channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
                            channel.BasicQos(0, 100, false)
        
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            Log.Error(exception);
                        }
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the answers in this Q&A? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839094/why-do-my-rabbitmq-channels-keep-closing especially the double Ack or Nack sent?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the problem is related to the fact that the event processing occurs in the same thread that is trying to access the RabbitMQ server, or there is a lock blocking the creation of the channel. The simplest solution I've found is to just use `Task.Run(() => )`

```
private async void RecreateChannel(object sender, ShutdownEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning($"Channel was shutdowned, whit reason: {e.ReplyText}, code: {e.ReplyCode}, trying to reconnect");

        _channel.Dispose();
        while (!_channel.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => _channel = InitChannel());
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _logger.LogError(exception, "Failed to recreate channel, trying again");
            }
        }
        _logger.LogInformation("Channel was recreated successfully");
    }
```